# Biggest set of rows that contain non-zero values in at least 'x' columns

Tags: python, algorithm

Sort of a convoluted, yet simple, matrix operation. I want find and maximize the # of rows such that there are at least `x` columns where the matrix constrained by those rows is all ones.

The rows themselves need not be contiguous nor the columns. And the matrix assumes that all the rows have at least `x` ones, hence, I am not removing any rows that don't have a minimum `x`.

**My initial approach is the following**: Take the first row. Find the first 'x' columns with 1s in them. Then for these columns, check how many rows also have 1s. Keep track of how many rows I found. Do this starting from each row.

However, this doesn't work, because, even for the first row, I also need to consider all the different column combinations that still give me minimum `x` columns with 1s in them, not just the first `x` columns.

The compute time quickly blows up for this. Is there an efficient way to approach this?

I'm trying to do it python.

Consider the following examples, and `x = 2`.

This doesn't have a solution since rows 1, 3, 5 are all initially eliminated. And then, for rows 2 and 4, there are no 3 columns that have ones in both rows.

[image]

But here, rows 2 and 4 have at least 3 columns where it is all 1s. So this has a solution, and the max rows are **2**.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide any sample input and the output?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be describing is a rephrasing of the association rule learning problem which can for example be solved with the Apriori algorithm.

Here is quick made example showing the basics of this algorithm. It might need some improvement and not sure if bug free.

Also it does not have the requirement that it has to find all different column combinations that give minimum of 'x' rows. It only uses 'x' to faster filter all solutions and eventually returns a solutions that is the biggest amount of columns with *at least* 'x' rows.

```
from operator import itemgetter, or_
from itertools import combinations, starmap
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial


class Apriori:

    def __init__(self, input, x):
        self.input = input
        self.cols = len(input[0])
        self.rows = len(input)
        self.x = x

    def _get_freq_combs(self, comb):
        return sum(map(lambda row:
                       sum([bool(e) for i, e in enumerate(row)
                            if i in comb]) // len(comb), self.input))

    def _make_new_combs(self, combs, comb_size):
        candidates = Counter(map(frozenset,
                                 starmap(or_, combinations(combs, 2))))
        possible_candidate_freq = factorial(comb_size) // factorial(2) \
            // factorial(comb_size - 2)
        for c, f in candidates.items():
            if f == possible_candidate_freq:
                yield c

    def solve(self):
        """Returns a list of sets with the most common items, at least x."""
        freq = [self._get_freq_combs([i]) for i in range(self.cols)]

        most_freq = [{ind} for ind in range(self.cols) if freq[ind] >= x]
        comb_size = 2
        while most_freq:
            old_freq = most_freq
            most_freq = [c for c in self._make_new_combs(most_freq, comb_size)
                         if self._get_freq_combs(c) >= x]
            comb_size += 1
        return old_freq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = [[1, 0, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 1, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 1]]
    x = 2
    apriori = Apriori(input, x)
    print(apriori.solve())
```

Comment: do you mean biggest amount of rows with at least 'x' columns?

Comment: @Jonathan No it does rows, but if you want columns you can just flip the matrix, or rewrite the code.